# Jenkins github plugin returns error 400 "Hook should contain event type"

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

At my company we have a Github Enterprise instance keeping all of our source in line, and Jenkins servers to do continuous integration. I'm using the Jenkins github plugin on Jenkins, and installing a service on Github to call MYJENKINS/github-webhook.

I would see the POSTs arriving from github on the jenkins server, but nothing would happen. The access log reports a 400 error being returned to github.

To find out what was being returned, I put tcpdump on the port. I now see that Jenkins is returning "Error 400 Hook should contain event type". It returns that for all repository events.

I can probably capture the github POST payload with tcpdump, but haven't done that yet.

My only guess at the moment is that our Github Enterprise installation is an earlier version than what is expected by the Jenkins github plug-in.

Update: As an experiment, on Github, I changed the call from a Service ("Jenkins github plugin") to a Webhook, but using the same URL MY_JENKINS/github-webhook/. THAT succeeds, is parsed successfully by the github plugin, and triggers the jobs that are watching a project/branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Github Enterprise should have webhook functionality built-in, so I'm a little unsure what you mean when you say you're installing a service on Github.

You can set up new webhooks by going to the following tab:

```
https://github-enterprise.com/my-org/myrepo >> Settings >> Webhooks & services
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

The other place to check is the settings in Jenkins, to make sure that it is set up to work with Github.

```
Jenkins >> Manage Jenkins >> Configure System >> Find: GitHub Plugin Configuration
```

In here, you need to provide your credentials for Github as well as the Github api url:

```
https://<github-enterprise.com>/api/v3/
```

*(You might be able to leave the 'Custom Github API URL' unchecked, but I haven't had good success with that.)*

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

The 'Credentials' would be an access token from Github.

```
Github >> Personal settings >> Personal access tokens
```

It's been a while since I've done setup like this, so feel free to correct me if I'm wrong about anything.

Comment: Yes, your post is what works. :) But there's another route to this functionality, perhaps a misleading route: In that section of the Github repository Settings page, there's "Webhooks & SERVICES". Under the SERVICES section (not Webhooks) there's a service called "Jenkins (Github plugin)" which has instructions to use the /github-webhook/ endpoint on Jenkins. If I use that service, the calls fail with the 400 error I mentioned in my question. Thank you for the elaboration!

Comment: Thanks for the great post but Suppose the job is triggered when a change is pushed to the github. Now how can i get the payloads in the jenkins so that I can parse to get the necessary information. In case of bitbucket simply the payload variable is available that we can directly use in jenkins but could not find for the github