# HTTP error 400 accessing /github-webhook/. Hook should contain event type

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, webhooks

I call webhook Jenkins from Gitlab and get following error :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Error 400 Hook should contain event type</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>HTTP ERROR 400</h2>
        <p>Problem accessing /github-webhook/. Reason:

            <pre>    Hook should contain event type</pre>
        </p>
        <hr>
        <i>
            <small>Powered by Jetty://</small>
        </i>
        <hr/>
    </body>
</html>
```

What i have done? i read reference here but not working :

[Jenkins github plugin returns error 400 "Hook should contain event type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36609629/jenkins-github-plugin-returns-error-400-hook-should-contain-event-type)

**Why i ask again to similar title:**

Cause the solution above still not working for me.

**What i can sure :**

I sure that Jenkins can connect to Gitlab, cause i can built project "X" manually and no error. My problem here when i want automatically build when i push to gitlab and i always get that error. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using **GitLab** with the **GitHub** plugin's webhook (`http://jenkins.example.com/github-webhook/`).

You should use one of these webhooks instead (assuming you can install the [GitLab Hook Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gitlab+Hook+Plugin)):

- `http://jenkins.example.com/gitlab/notify_commit`
- `http://jenkins.example.com/gitlab/build_now`

Ref: https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-hook-plugin#build-now-hook